# Angular: How to get rid of ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this little sample of a select-box that is generated by the content of a Map.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqccjn

**Class**

```
public map : Map <string, string> = new Map <string, string> ([
    [ "NEW", "?" ],
    [ "ACCEPTED", "&#10003;" ],
    [ "DECLINED", "&#10005;" ]
]);
```

**Component**

```
<select>
        <option *ngFor="let m of map.keys()" [innerHTML]="map.get(m)"></option>
</select>
```

I do not know why I get this Java Runtime Exception.

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngForOf: [object Map Iterator]'. Current value: 'ngForOf: [object Map Iterator]'."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will re-evaluate the `map.keys()` on every cycle, causing it to get a new object every time. You better store this immediately somewhere like this:

```
public map : Map <string, string> = new Map <string, string> ([
    [ "NEW", "?" ],
    [ "ACCEPTED", "&#10003;" ],
    [ "DECLINED", "&#10005;" ]
]);

public mapEntries = Array.from(this.map.entries());
```

and your template:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let m of mapEntries" [value]="m[0]">{{m[1]}}</option>
</select>
```

Another way is to keep it like you had, and use the `OnPush` change detection strategy, which is anyways recommended for performance reasons:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```